# Python consecutive if statements

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement

I recently missed parenthesis in an if statement in the code and code still works.

```
a = True  
b = False  
c = True  
if a if b else c:  
    print 'Hello'
```

I used K-map to get the solution and this statement is equivalent to

```
(a and b) or (not b and c)
```

Can anyone explain why is this happening?

Comment: You have a conditional expression. `truevalue if test else falsevalue`. Since `b` is `False`, `c` is returned here.

Comment: yeah.. but conditional statement doesn't end with a colon.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. But the `if <expression>:` statement *does*.

Comment: ah! I get it.. so it is equivalent to                                                                      if (a if b else c): print 'Hello'